# Identifying where E-Mails are coming from

Tags: email

I'm setting up several blogs and it would be handy if they could all use the same email address for contact forms and mailto's. So is there a correct way of adding a unique ID or Reference to the path to help identify where users are coming from?

i.e. `myemailaddress@gmail.com?from=website1`

Comment: Pass in there source as a parameter.  What are you setting this up in? If Ruby On Rails I'll give you a thorough answer but basically you're doing it the correct way adding it as a 'get request' parameter.

Comment: Basically I just want it to show up in my email inbox with the name of the website. It's more for personal reasons than to make the website function in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convention is to append `+something` to the user part of the email address. This is called [subaddressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Sub-addressing).

```
you+something@example.com
```

Mail servers are commonly configured to ignore the `+something` when determining what mailbox to put the message in (so it would be delivered to `you@example.com`) but the full address will appear in the email so you can filter on it (or perform whatever other tests you wish).

(NB: Commonly is not universally, so you'll have to make sure that your mail server is set up that way and modify it if it isn't).

Comment: I'm going to be using G-Mail via google initially. But I may also use Thunderbird at some point in the future too

Comment: Just looked at your linked webpage and can see GMail listed, but what is `plus`?

Comment: GMail supports it.

Comment: plus is the `+` character as used in my example

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. Thanks, this is going to be very useful.